# Wrap single quotes and replace line break by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the strings as below

```
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
Autism Partnership School
```

I want to change it by regex as below:

```
'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School', 'Autism Partnership School',
```

I have tried `replace(/^(.*)$/, '$&',)` then `replace(/\r\n/, '')` and it works. But I don't want to do the replace two time, so I combine this syntax to `replace(/^(.*)$\r\n/, '$&',)`. Could someone please advise why my syntax is not work?

Thank you.

Live demo
http://regexr.com?37nk7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regex, you should be able to use this:

```
replace(/^(.*)$[\r\n]*/g, "'$1', ")
```

The `[\r\n]*` is simply to account for different EOL scenarios, just in case. Then the `$1` serves as the back-reference for a single group, and the trailing `g` at the end of the regexp object is the "global" flag for performing the replacement globally.

Updated demo: http://regexr.com?37nkd

Answer (score -1):

```
implode("', '", explode("\n", $longString))
```

Edit #1:
Ooops, forget the JS not PHP.

```
var longStringArray = longString.split("\n");
var newLongString = longStringArray.join("', '");
```

Comment: -1, sorry: JavaScript does not have such functions. (I think you're thinking of PHP?)